# Using an array in SQL IN

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

Two part question...(note that I'm using a PostGres)

My SQL query is formatted like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://something?q=SELECT *database_final_form_merge where territory in ("+terrs+")",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
     success: function(data) {
      }
       });
```

The variable `terrs` is an array like this:

`["D1VE3011", "D1VE3011", "D1VD2209", "D1VD2209", "D1VD2103", "D1VD2103"]`

This formats the SQL query like this though:

```
SELECT* from database_final_form_merge where territory IN (D1VE3011,D1VE3011,D1VD2209,D1VD2209,D1VD2103,D1VD2103)
```

But it needs to be in this format (I think):

```
SELECT* from database_final_form_merge where territory IN ('D1VE3011','D1VE3011','D1VD2209','D1VD2209','D1VD2103','D1VD2103')
```

This works when I try it directly without an AJAX GET. Is there a different way I should be passing this array?

That's question 1.

Question 2...is there a way to pass that array so that only unique values are passed? You'll note that in my array there are duplicates, but wondering if there's a way to only pass along unique values.

Thanks.

Comment: That is the perfect, self-serving recipe for SQL injections.

Comment: @vitaly-1  I'm passing this to a SaaS platform that steralizes everything before running the queries to ensure this doesn't happen

Comment: Do you have the authority to create a table on the database?  If so, depending on how large the lists can get, you might get significant gains in efficiency by loading your values into a table (using some form of PostgreSQL's copy command, which is lightning-quick) and doing a join or a semi-join on that table.  If you have, for example, 1,000 entries, I'll bet the time of compiling the statement alone will be signficiant compared to this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put passing query as a parameter aside and get into the problem.

For the question 2 you can use
[jQuery.unique](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

And for the former question:

`"('" + terrs.join("','") + "')"` generates `('D1VE3011','D1VE3011','D1VD2209','D1VD2209','D1VD2103','D1VD2103')` part.

Mind the white spaces though. You might end up with string like this

`'(' D1VD2209',' D1VD2103','D1VD2103 ')`

*EDITED accordingly

Comment: I'm not using PHP, so using `$_GET['arr']` won't work. Is there another way to format?

Comment: oh... or simply replacing the `("+terrs+")"` with `('" + terrs.join("','") + "')"` should work?

Comment: This was the simple solution.  I created a new variable that did the join first and then passed that into my AJAX call.